# Js chess call sub function

Tags: javascript

My question is: How is it possible to call the function mova from outside the function init?

init.mova("a2-a3"); doesn't work

The full code is here.

This is a chessboard system.
I don't now how to call the function mova from outside init. init.mova doesn't work.

Code:

```
var init = function() {

        //--- start example JS ---
        var board,
              game = new Chess(),
              statusEl = $('#status'),
              fenEl = $('#fen'),
              pgnEl = $('#pgn');

            // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
            // only pick up pieces for the side to move
            var onDragStart = function(source, piece, position, orientation) {
              if (game.game_over() === true ||
                  (game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
                  (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
                return false;
              }
            };

            var onDrop = function(source, target) {
              // see if the move is legal
              var move = game.move({
                from: source,
                to: target,
                promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
              });
              if (move !== null) {
              console.log(move.to);
                }
              // illegal move
              if (move === null) return 'snapback';

              updateStatus();
            };

            // update the board position after the piece snap 
            // for castling, en passant, pawn promotion
            var onSnapEnd = function() {
              board.position(game.fen());
            };

            var updateStatus = function() {
              var status = '';

              var moveColor = 'White';
              if (game.turn() === 'b') {
                moveColor = 'Black';
              }

              // checkmate?
              if (game.in_checkmate() === true) {
                status = 'Game over, ' + moveColor + ' is in checkmate.';
              }

              // draw?
              else if (game.in_draw() === true) {
                status = 'Game over, drawn position';
              }

              // game still on
              else {
                status = moveColor + ' to move';

                // check?
                if (game.in_check() === true) {
                  status += ', ' + moveColor + ' is in check';
                }
              }

              statusEl.html(status);
              fenEl.html(game.fen());
              pgnEl.html(game.pgn());
            };

            var cfg = {
              draggable: true,
              position: 'start',
              onDragStart: onDragStart,
              onDrop: onDrop,
              onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
            };
            board = new ChessBoard('board', cfg);

            updateStatus();
        //--- end example JS ---

        var mova = function(positie) {
            board.move(positie);
        }
        }; // end init()
        $(document).ready(init);
```

init.mova("a2-a3");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables defined within a function are [scoped to that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). They cannot be called from outside of the function.

If you wanted a quick and dirty fix, you could define the variable `mova` outside the `init()` function, and then assign its value within it.

```
var mova;

var init = function() {
  // etc. etc.
  mova = function(positie) {
    board.move(positie);
  }
}
```

then, the `mova` function would be available outside of the init function **once it has run**.

You could ensure that you don't try to use the function until it's defined by using a function that is called when your init completes:

```
var mova;

var init = function() {
  // etc. etc.
  mova = function(positie) {
    board.move(positie);
  }
  onInitComplete();
}

function onInitComplete() {
  // function using mova function
}
```

It's likely, given the structure of your program, that you will want to use the same technique for many variables other than just `mova`. You probably don't want all of your game logic inside the `init()` function. You could define some variables for the state of your game *outside* the init function and then just assign them their starting values *inside* it. Hope that helps.